# Manipulating Exponents in Functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K=\langle x\rangle$ and $H$ be any group. Let $\phi_1,\phi_2:K\rightarrow \text{Aut}(H)$ such that $\phi_1(K),\phi_2(K)$ are conjugate subgroups of $\text{Aut}(H)$. Since $\phi_1(K),\phi_2(K)$ are conjugate subgroups of $\text{Aut}(H)$, we know $\exists$ $\varphi\in\text{Aut}(H)$ where $\varphi\phi_1(K)\varphi^{-1}=\phi_2(K)$.

Then $\varphi\phi_1(x)\varphi^{-1}\in\phi_2(K)$.  This means $\varphi\phi_1(x)\varphi^{-1}=\phi_2(y)$ for some $y\in K$. Because $K$ is cyclic, we know $y=x^a$ such that $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now let $k\in K$ be arbitrary. Again because $K$ is cyclic, we know $k=x^b$ such that $b\in \mathbb{Z}$. Consider

\begin{eqnarray*}
\varphi \phi_1(k) \varphi^{-1}&=&\varphi \phi_1(x^b) \varphi^{-1} \text{ because $k=x^b$}\\
&=& \varphi [\phi_1(x)]^b \varphi^{-1}\\
&=& [\varphi \phi_1(x) \varphi^{-1}]^{b}
\end{eqnarray*}

Why am I able to state the last two equivalences? This is not clear to me. My intuition tells me it is true because otherwise I would not be able to complete the problem. But I haven't been able to convince myself that this is true. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Presumably you intend $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ to be group homomorphisms.  Set $b = 2$ and expand the terms in both those equalities and simplify.  The pattern should be obvious, but to prove it you can use induction.

Comment: @DerekElkins I am afraid I getting stuck on setting $b=2$ to see the pattern. And yes $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are homomorphisms.

Comment: Oh just kidding. I see it now. For the first, $\varphi\phi_1(x)\phi_1(x)\varphi^{-1}=\varphi\phi_1(xx)\varphi^{-1}=\varphi\phi_1(x^2)\varphi^{-1}$. I will try applying induction now.